# How to select unique cell records from table including all rows and columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite

For instance there is a table like that:

```
ID    Name    Street    Number    Code
100   John    Street1   1         1234
130   Peter   Street1   2         1234
135   John    Street2   1         5678
141   Alice   Street5   3         5678
160   John    Street1   3         1234
```

I should make a query by using sqlite. I want to investigate every columns and rows and get the unique cell values. For instance in this example result must be:

```
100, 130, 135, 141, 160, John, Peter, Alice, Street1, Street2, Street5, 1, 2, 3, 5678, 1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union`:

```
select id as val from t
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select name from t
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select street from t
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select number from t
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select code from t
```